# SQL Server Namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to read an XML file from SQL Server. I think it's a problem with Namespace..
This is an example of my simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfStatistica xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveUpdateWS">
   <Statistica>
       <BuildFinale>68</BuildFinale>
       <BuildIniziale>1</BuildIniziale>
       <DataInserimento>2014-11-21T09:34:25.387</DataInserimento>
       <IdCliente>-1</IdCliente>
       <IdOperazione>4</IdOperazione>
       <IdRivenditore>-1</IdRivenditore>
       <IdTipoProdotto>-1</IdTipoProdotto>
       <IdUtente>2</IdUtente>
       <IdVersione>3</IdVersione>
   </Statistica>
   <Statistica>
        <BuildFinale>68</BuildFinale>
        <BuildIniziale>1</BuildIniziale>
        <DataInserimento>2014-11-21T09:37:43.84</DataInserimento>
        <IdCliente>-1</IdCliente>
        <IdOperazione>4</IdOperazione>
        <IdRivenditore>-1</IdRivenditore>
        <IdTipoProdotto>-1</IdTipoProdotto>
        <IdUtente>2</IdUtente>
        <IdVersione>3</IdVersione>
   </Statistica>
</ArrayOfStatistica>
```

With the following code:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveUpdateWS"' AS ArrayOfStatistica)
SELECT
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdStatistica)[1]', 'bigint')),    
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdUtente)[1]', 'int')),       
    (CASE WHEN Child.value('(IdRivenditore)[1]', 'int') = -1 THEN NULL else (SELECT Child.value('(IdRivenditore)[1]', 'int')) end),     
    (CASE WHEN Child.value('(IdCliente)[1]', 'int') = -1 THEN NULL else (SELECT Child.value('(IdCliente)[1]', 'int')) end),
    (SELECT Child.value('(DataInserimento)[1]', 'datetime')),               
    (CASE WHEN Child.value('(IdTipoProdotto)[1]', 'int') = -1 THEN NULL else (SELECT Child.value('(IdTipoProdotto)[1]', 'int')) end),
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdVersione)[1]', 'int')),
    (SELECT Child.value('(BuildIniziale)[1]', 'bigint')),
    (SELECT Child.value('(BuildFinale)[1]', 'bigint')),
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdOperazione)[1]', 'int'))

    FROM
    @xmlfile.nodes('ArrayOfStatistica/Statistica') AS N(Child)
```

I do not get any value from SELECT.

How should I set the namespace for this xml file? 
If I remove the lines for the XML namespace

```
<ArrayOfStatistica xmlns =
"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveUpdateWS" xmlns: i =
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema -instance ">
```

everything works fine.

Comment: Why do you have `(SELECT Child.value(...))` in each column, instead of just `Child.value(...)`? Why do you think you need the namespace line? (I mean, if it works without it, then just go without it?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, then you *either* define a **default** XML namespace that gets applied without using an explicit prefix, or you define a XML namespace with a **prefix** that you need to use in your XPath expressions.

To use the **default** XML namespace, use this statement:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveUpdateWS')
```

and then your existing XPath expressions (without any prefixes) *should* work.

If you define a **prefix**, when you have to **use** that prefix in your XPath expressions!

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveUpdateWS' AS ns)

SELECT
    Child.value('(ns:IdStatistica)[1]', 'bigint'),    
    Child.value('(ns:IdUtente)[1]', 'int'),       
    .......    
FROM
    @xmlfile.nodes('ns:ArrayOfStatistica/ns:Statistica') AS N(Child)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that all your elements are in namespace `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveUpdateWS`, you can use [`DEFAULT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) (Note also the typo in your namespace - you have an extra trailing `"`)

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LiveUpdateWS')
SELECT
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdStatistica)[1]', 'bigint')),    
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdUtente)[1]', 'int')),       
    (CASE WHEN Child.value('(IdRivenditore)[1]', 'int') = -1 THEN NULL else (SELECT Child.value('(IdRivenditore)[1]', 'int')) end),     
    (CASE WHEN Child.value('(IdCliente)[1]', 'int') = -1 THEN NULL else (SELECT Child.value('(IdCliente)[1]', 'int')) end),
    (SELECT Child.value('(DataInserimento)[1]', 'datetime')),               
    (CASE WHEN Child.value('(IdTipoProdotto)[1]', 'int') = -1 THEN NULL else (SELECT Child.value('(IdTipoProdotto)[1]', 'int')) end),
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdVersione)[1]', 'int')),
    (SELECT Child.value('(BuildIniziale)[1]', 'bigint')),
    (SELECT Child.value('(BuildFinale)[1]', 'bigint')),
    (SELECT Child.value('(IdOperazione)[1]', 'int'))
    FROM
    @xmlfile.nodes('ArrayOfStatistica/Statistica') AS N(Child)
```